# How to get records for particular time range in a month

Tags: mysql

I want to get records for a time range in a month in mysql.I have made a query to clear the sense of my question which is given as below:

```
SELECT * FROM db.alarming 
WHERE receive_time LIKE '2015-01%'and receive_time <= '%19:00%' and receive_time >= '%18:30%';
```

where receive_time is a datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
SELECT * FROM db.alarming WHERE
    receive_time BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31' AND
    TIME(receive_time) BETWEEN '18:30' AND '19:00';
```

Not any date in January of 2015 is valid. So you need to extract the time value and apply a second restriction also.

Comment: thank you very much. Time(receive_time) this is what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Use between

```
SELECT * FROM db.alarming 
WHERE receive_time between '2015-03-01 06:15:00' and '2015-03-31 06:15:00';
```

Comment: This selects all the days between 1st and 31st.He wants only the data from each day which lies in time interval 1830 and 1900

Comment: well i didn't quite understand his question